# Anyone know how to put a .net control in a google maps InfoWindow?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, google-maps

I was looking at some basic google maps stuff and found the following code on one of google's intro pages.

I used it as my POC and created a .net project from the concept.  I now have markers and infoWindows being populated from the database which is pretty cool.

My problem is I want to add InfoWindows in a slick way (not only to the map, but also save to the db).  Instead of having .net controls outside of the map window I want to be able to add info to the map directly.  If the user clicks in the map I would like to be able to add a marker and InfoWindow with asp controls in the window (textbox and button).

Anyone know how to do this?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            title here
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function mapParamsInitialize() 
            {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
                var contentString = '<div id="content"> Here is some text that will display in an infoWindow, or \'bubble\' </div>'; 
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString }); 
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng, map: map, title: "Custom Window here" }); 
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () { infowindow.open(map, marker); });
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="mapParamsInitialize()">
        <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a div tag and set Z-index dynamically or if possible try to use some Asp.net pop up control which you can call from client side. I had a similar requirement and I was able to manage it with Devexpress AspxPopup control. Popup control then had an Iframe within it to load information from a database.

Comment: As my example outlines, the controls are all javascript and not visual studio controls.  Do you have an example of what you did that allows nice integration with the js api while using .net controls?